# Is it possible to convert non-bootable USB to bootable USB?

Tags: linux, macos, usb

I have been trying to install Kali Linux and get it to run on my Mac but I have had problems with both DVDs and USBs. I probably may be doing something wrong.

What I have been trying to do is to burn the Kali Linux iso on to a DVD-R disk and when it finished they say something like "couldn't burn this information to the disk" then the disk is corrupted and can't be used. In Disk Utility it says that my USBs and my DVDs are non bootable when I click on a drive and get more info.

**Is there a way I can convert the format of it in such a way I can make it bootable?**

[image: Photo of USB details]

Comment: afaik, you need rEFind to boot nix on a Mac

Comment: does the USB have to read bootable to be bootable?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a boot disk for Mac must be formatted "Apple HFS Journaled with a GUID partition table.
That is what I use when I create bootable USB thumb drives.

Comment: What a is GUID partition and did your thumb drives ever read non bootable?